# Architecture of code using node js

Tags: node.js, data-structures, architecture

I am having problems with my code architecture and am looking for advice. I am sending multiple read request to a server via udp and printing the read response out. An example of how the request and response look are below. I am getting the response back as one large hex string starting at 0008.. I need a way for the code to know how many addresses were sent to be read and what data size was requested and take that into account on printing out the data. Since the data size can change, I can not just split the string up using a definite value. I am not looking for actual code but rather just some ideas on how one could tackle this.

```
Request
    00 06 - Opcode
    00 00 - Block #
    02 - Count
    34 97 00 20 - Address 1
    04 00 - Data Size 1 (bytes)
    30 97 00 20 - Address 2 
    01 00 - Data Size 2 (bytes)


Response- 00080001e60300009
    00 08 - Opcode
    00 01 - Block # 
    e6 03 00 00 - Data 1
    09 - Data 2

  What I am printing right now- e603000009
  How I want it printed - Address 1 = e6030000
                          Address 2 = 09  ...

                          Address 3 = 00 00
                          etc. 
  (it would know what it is a new data by the data size that was requested and the # of addresses that were requested)
```

Part of code where I am sending a read request and emitting it to html

```
app.post('/output3', function(req, res){

  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/upload3.html');
 //Define the host and port values of UDP

  var HOST= '192.168.0.136';
  var PORT= 69;    

    var io = require('socket.io')(http);

    //Mulitple parameters
    //setInterval will send message constantly.
    var client= dgram.createSocket('udp4');
    var counter = 0;

      //array for addresses
      var address=[];
      //array for size
      var size=[];
      //iterate through all addresses and convert to little endian
      for (var i=0; i<req.body.address.length; i++) {
        var n= req.body.address[i];
        var s = n.toString(16).match(/.{1,2}/g);
        address[i]= s.reverse().join("").toString(16); // ==> "0x985c0020" (= 2556166176)
      }

      //iterate through all size and make hex strings and little endian
      for (var i=0; i<req.body.size.length; i++) {
        function pad(number, length) {
          var my_string = '' + number;
          while (my_string.length < length) {
            my_string = '0' + my_string;
          }
          return my_string;
        }

        var n2= pad(req.body.size[i], 4);
        var s2 = n2.toString(16).match(/.{1,2}/g);
        size[i]= s2.reverse().join("").toString(16);
      }

      //empty string to add address and size together
      var x='';
      for (var i=0; i<req.body.address.length; i++) {
        x += address[i]+size[i];
      }

        console.log(req.body.size);
      var mrq= read(x);

      //Open listener to recieve intial message and print in to webpage
      io.on('connection', function(socket){
        var mrq= read(x);
          io.emit('mrq', mrq);
        });
      function read() {
        // Memory Read Request is a 16-bit word with a value of 6
        var message = '0006'
        // Block number is a 16-bit word that we will always set to 0
        message += '0000'
        // Count is variable, and calculated by the size of the parameter list
        message += '02'

        for (var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
          message += arguments[i];
        }
        return message;
      }


      var message = new Buffer(mrq, 'hex');
      counter++;

      var loop= setInterval(function () {
      //Sends packets to UDP and setInterval sends packets again for specific time
      client.send(message, 0, message.length, PORT, HOST, function (err, bytes) {
        if (err) throw err;
      });
      if (counter === 1000000000000000) {
        clearInterval(loop);
      }
    }, 1/50);



    //Open listener to recieve intial message and print in to webpage
    io.on('connection', function(socket){
      client.on('message', function( message, rinfo ){
        //hex string
        var temp = message.readUIntBE(0, 2);
        //console.log(message.toString(16));
        io.emit('temp', temp);
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Showing your current code would help us answer this better.

but in general, the way would be to use a write stream and push your string out in chunks, rather than as a whole block.